# Why to create Angular routes if you already defined Express routes?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm new in MEAN stack area and I have some doubts related to Angular routes. Why should I recreate on the client side the routes already made in backend with express.js, what are the benefits?  Is this the only way how Angular.js works? I saw some examples with Jade.js and it wasn’t necessary to recreate the routes on the client side, making the things simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't specifically used Angular myself, but I have used Backbone.js for the same purpose, and the same arguments apply.

There are many use cases where it makes sense to define routes on the client side, not the server side. For instance, I do a lot of work with Phonegap using Backbone, and the architecture is generally a REST API for the back end, and the data gets used to render the pages on the client side. This approach has the advantage that it reduces the amount of data sent over the network, generally making the app quicker. Client-side routing also preserves browser history when compared to just updating the existing content via AJAX.

Ultimately, it's something you have to consider on a case-by-case basis. For something that's very dynamic, building it as a single page web app with client-side routing may make sense. For a more traditional web app, such as a blog or ecommerce site, you're probably better off defining routes on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have a question. Do you mean that I don't need anymore to define the routes on the backend if I use Angular for a SPA? I followed some tutorials and in all of them, the authors are created on both sides the same routes. So, I'm still confuze :) .

Comment: @Webdesigner In practice, it tends to be that you'll define routes on both sides. For a web app (as opposed to just an API), you'll typically have one that serves the main page, and the static files are referenced in the HTML, and then all the rest of the interaction is done via AJAX. You may need additional routes on the server side, too - for instance, if you need to log in and out, it makes sense to have those handled on the server side.